# Is hg glog possible in reverse order?

Tags: mercurial

I know that the order of `hg log` can be reversed by calling `hg log -r:`. Then the oldest commit is topmost and the newest item is at the bottom.

Is something similar possible for `hg glog` (or `hg log -G`) from the [graphlog](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GraphlogExtension) extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't reverse it, but you can restrict it to a certain range using the `--rev` option.

```
hg glog --rev 0:1
```

and

```
hg glog --rev 1:0
```

both show revision 1 above revision 0, but you're at least seeing the tail end of the output.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the -G option as it is used for printing the 'tree' (see --o--o).
What you can use is the predicate 'sort' from [hg revsets](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revsets):

```
"sort(set[, [-]key... [, ...]])"
```

> Sort set by keys. The default sort order is ascending, specify a key
>   as "-key" to sort in descending order. The keys can be:
>
> - "rev" for the revision number,
> - "branch" for the branch name,
> - "desc" for the commit message (description),
> - "user" for user name ("author"    can be used as an alias),
> - "date" for the commit date "topo" for a    reverse topographical sort

---

**e.g. 2**: to print the last 10 commits in reverse order:

```
$ hg log --rev 'sort(last(:,10), -rev)'
```

Where:

- `last(:,10)` revision set takes the last 10 commits from all commits
- `sort(revset, -rev)` sorts the revision revset in reverse order

---

**e.g. 1** print all changesets not belonging to the base repo in reverse order

```
$ hg log -r "sort(ancestors(.), -rev) and outgoing('ssh://hg@your/external/repo')"
```

Where:

- `ancestors(.)` revision set takes all commits from the current branch
- `and outgoing()` results in only keeping the outgoing changesets